# Why does the facebook debugger redirects?

Tags: facebook

I have a "http" (developer) page, which is enabled for the facebook, its visible from the outside. When I want to debug it with https://developers.facebook.com/, it shows everything OK:

```
Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    http://my.dev.com/id/3161304
Canonical URL:  http://my.dev.com/id/3161304/
Redirect Path:  
Input URL           ->  http://my.dev.com/id/3161304
301 HTTP Redirect   ->  http://my.dev.com/id/3161304/
```

I have this site cloned, for testing, https-ed. The result is different:

first, some parameters are missing:

```
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description
```

Secondly, the response:

```
Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    https://my.cloned.site.com/id/3161304/
Canonical URL:  https://my.cloned.site.com/id/
Redirect Path   
Input URL:                ->    https://my.cloned.site.com/id/3161304/
rel="canonical" Meta Tag  ->    https://my.cloned.site.com/id/
```

it seems that a redirect happens. Why?

Comment: `rel="canonical" Meta Tag`

Comment: but its "<link rel="canonical" href="http://my.site.com/id/" />" at the developer and <link rel="canonical" href="//my.cloned.site.com/id/" /> at the cloned one, so kinda the same

Comment: Then it should not work properly for your original site to begin with ... what does the debug tool say about that? If the canonical URL is not it, then you will need to investigate further how your system behaves when a request is made by the Facebook scraper - fake the user agent it sends, and then log what happens inside your scripts ...